# Parameterization of the Schwarz P surface

Tags: differential-geometry, closed-form, parametrization, minimal-surfaces

Is there a closed form parameterization of the [Schwarz P minimal surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_minimal_surface)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following description is adapted and corrected from [Gandy and Klinowski (2000), Exact computation of the triply periodic Schwarz P minimal surface, Chemical Physics Letters **322**, 579–586](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223147236_Exact_computation_of_the_triply_periodic_Schwarz_P_minimal_surface). The expression for $z$ below is a major correction, also talked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3854953/357390).

Let $w$ be a complex number with $0\le\arg(w)\le\frac\pi4$ and $|w+e^{i\pi/4}|\le\sqrt2$. The following coordinates, viewed as functions of $w$, give a fundamental patch of the P surface:
$$x=-\kappa\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac1{\sqrt8}F\left(\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt8w}{\sqrt{w^4+4w^2+1}},\frac14\right)\right)$$
$$y=\kappa\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac1{\sqrt8}F\left(\sin^{-1}\frac{-\sqrt8w}{\sqrt{w^4+4w^2+1}},\frac34\right)\right)$$
$$z=-\kappa\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac1{2+\sqrt3}F\left(\sin^{-1}\frac{w^2}{2-\sqrt3},97-56\sqrt3\right)\right)$$
$\kappa=\frac2{K(3/4)}$ is a normalising factor and arguments to elliptic integrals $F,K$ follow the conventions of Mathematica/mpmath. Now take this patch and transform it according to the following $12$ transformation matrices:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-q&-q&0&0\\-q&q&0&1\\0&0&1&\frac12
\end{array}\right]\text{and all permutations of rows}$$
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
q&q&0&1\\q&-q&0&0\\0&0&-1&\frac12
\end{array}\right]\text{and all permutations of rows}$$
Here $q=\frac{\sqrt2}2$ and applying the transformation $[\mathbf A\mid\mathbf b]$ to a point $\mathbf x$ gives $\mathbf{Ax}+\mathbf b$. The union of the $12$ transformed patches is a hexagonal plate within the cube $[0,1]^3$:

[image]

Mirroring this plate in the coordinate planes gives a unit cell of the Schwarz P surface with side length $2$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the long-sought answer!

Comment: This is the clearest explanation I have seen on how to do this. I am actually having trouble starting from the fundamental patch to the hexagonal plate. My patch looks right but the transformations scatter them all about instead of creating the 8th of a unit cell expected. Any immediate thoughts as to why that would be?