# Find the closed form of the expression

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

$$ P(x) = \frac{4x^6}{(1-x)^2(1-2x)} $$

How do I make a $$ P(n) $$ in closed form of expression? Any tips would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $P(n)$ is already in closed form... "not closed form" usually means "involving integrals", like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3865591/357390).

Comment: not even sure what you are looking for

Comment: I guess $P(n)=\frac{4n^6}{(1-n)^2(1-2n)}$.

Comment: What about $\displaystyle\frac{4n^6}{(1-n)^2(1-2n)}?$.

Comment: Do you want to find the sequence that is related to $P(x)$ as a generating function?

Comment: You may find [OEIS sequence A258547](https://oeis.org/A258547) of interest. The sequence begins: $16,44,104,228,480,988,2008,\dots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\sum_{n\ge 0}p_n x^n= \frac{4 x^6}{(1 - 2 x) (1 - x)^2}.$$
Via partial fraction decomposition,
\begin{align}
\frac{4 x^6}{(1 - 2 x) (1 - x)^2} 
&= -\frac{49}{4} - \frac{17}{2}x - 5 x^2 - 2 x^3 + \frac{16}{1-x} - \frac{4}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{1}{4 (1-2 x)} \\
&= -\frac{49}{4} - \frac{17}{2}x - 5 x^2 - 2 x^3 + 16\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n - 4\sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{n+1}{1} x^n + \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n\ge 0} (2x)^n \\
&= -\frac{49}{4} - \frac{17}{2}x - 5 x^2 - 2 x^3 + \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(12 - 4n +  2^{n-2}\right) x^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies that
\begin{align}
p_n &= -\frac{49}{4}[n=0] - \frac{17}{2}[n=1] - 5[n=2] - 2[n=3] + 12 - 4n +  2^{n-2} \\
&= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $0 \le n \le 3$} \\ 12 - 4n +  2^{n-2} &\text{if $n > 3$}\end{cases}
\end{align}